# Rusts "cross" command not found after successful installation

Tags: rust, cross-platform

To cross-compile with Rust, the `cross` program exists. To use it Docker needs to run without root permissions (it does) and `cross` needs to be installed, with e.g. `cargo install cross -f` (it is). I did this without root rights.

But if I run in the same terminal `cross`, I always get an error: "cross: Command not found.", even after a restart. Despite every tutorial telling me `cargo install cross...` should be enough.

Edit: I saw that the problem is that "~/.cargo/bin/" wasn't added to the path variable.

Edit 2: I used the recommended way to install Rust with rustup, but cargo was put into `/snap/bin/cargo` (maybe thanks to Ubuntu?). While I think I can fix my problem with adding `~/.cargo/bin` to my path variable, I would like to know what's the best way, so everything is put into the same place.

(I use Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on an AMD64 platform.)

Comment: Is your question "how to add to PATH"? Because there are a multitude of resources available to you with a simple search.

Comment: *"~/.cargo/bin/ wasn't added to the path variable"* - how did you install cargo?

Comment: I installed it via `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`, suggested from "https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install". The difference is, that my cargo bin landed in "/snap/bin/cargo" (I think thanks to Ubuntu) and not in "~/.cargo/bin", which is the directory where it should land according to the official rustup website.